# Unity C# How do I change a variable from a different class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I change the variable in another class?

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isDead = false;


    void Start () {


        GameObject Slugbert = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("Slugbert"));

    }


    void Update () {



    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the isDead boolean from false to true.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour {






    public GameObject obj;

    Manager manager;

    public int maxHealth = 10;
    public int health = 10;
    public GameObject deathInstance = null;
    public Vector2 deathInstanceOffset = new Vector2(0,0);


    void Start () {
        manager = obj.GetComponent<Manager>();
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey ("up")) {

            Debug.Log ("Self Destruct Activated");
            TakeDamage();


        }

    }

    public void TakeDamage()
    {



        health -= 100;

        if (health <= 0)
        {


            OnKill();
            Debug.Log ("Running it");

        }
    }

    public void OnKill()
    {

        manager.isDead = true;
        Debug.Log(manager.isDead);


        if (deathInstance) {
            var pos = gameObject.transform.position;
            GameObject deathObject = Instantiate (deathInstance, new Vector3(pos.x + deathInstanceOffset.x, pos.y + deathInstanceOffset.y, pos.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        }


        Destroy(gameObject);
    }





}
```

I've added in a debug.log showing the value of manager.isDead, and it's printing true, however in the inspector when I run it and click on GameControl, the object containing Manager.cs it shows that isDead = false.  I'm not sure how I get the value of isDead in GameControl Manager.cs to equal true.

Thanks, I'm pretty new to Unity

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Not every `NullReferenceException` has the same scenario.

Comment: @Shaharyar: When there is a `NullReferenceException` on the line `manager.isDead = true;`, there is only one possible scenario, namely `manager` being `null`. The OP doesn't seem to get to that conclusion, so their question boils **exactly** down to the question I linked - "What does this mean, and what can I do about it?"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I just meant we should point out the actual problem there causing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're having that error is because unity doesn't know what this `Manager` is.
In unity, a script cannot automatically recognize other scripts, even though it is located in the same folder or game object.
In order to access other scripts, you need to assign the variable `manager` with the actual script `manager.cs`.  Here's how:

**Health.cs**

```
// This is the game object where manager.cs is attached to.
// Assign the game object from the inspector, drag drop the game object to this field.
// If manager.cs and health.cs is in the same game object, you don't need this.
public GameObject obj;
Manager manager;

void Start () {
    health = maxHealth;

    // This is where you actually assign manager variable
    // GetComponent<Manager> meaning you want to get a game object component with
    // type Manager, which is your script manager.cs
    // If manager.cs and health.cs is in the same game object, replace "obj" with
    // "gameObject"
    manager = obj.GetComponent<Manager>();
}
```

And then you should be able to change the variable like you wanted. Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem :) I'm just trying to help

Answer (score 0):

The manager property is not set yet in the class Health.

Change `Manager manager;` into `Manager manager = new Manager();`

You are not changing a variable from another class but you are changing the property of an object of a certain class.

Comment: This is fixing the error but it's not changing the variable

Comment: What do you mean by changing a variable. The object of class Health has a property manager which is an object of class Manager. With this modification you can now set the property isDead of this property.

Comment: How do I do that though?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is unclear. So here two possible variants of what you are trying to do:
**1. You have two objects in scene and on the first you attached Manager.cs and on the second you attached Health.cs.**
Solution in this case:
 **a.** in Health.cs modify Manager manager; -> **public** Manager manager; ( in that case you wil be able to se a field in inspector when you choose the second object. 
 **b.** Select the second object in scene, lock (press small lock icon) inspector
 **c.** Select the first object and drag&drop it to the Manager field of the second object.

**2. You have one object and both scripts attached to it.**
 Solution:
add to Start function in Health.cs 
`void Start () {
        health = maxHealth;
        manager = gameObject.GetComponent<Manager>();
      }`

Answer (score 0):

try to change
 `public bool isDead = false;`
to

```
public static bool isDead = false;
```

in Manager Class and change remaining accordingly